# Missing exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

$\frac{256}{2^S}=64$

How would you solve for S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FURTHER HINT: $\mathrm{log}_2(2^{x}) = x$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $256=2^8$, $64=2^6$, and remember the rule $2^x/2^y = 2^{x-y}$.

Comment: Another hint: $256/64 = 2^S$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to your problem.
$$\frac{256}{2^s}=64$$
$$256 = 64\cdot2^s$$
Since $64 = 2^6$ and $256 = 2^8$ the equation becomes:
$$2^8 = 2^6\cdot 2^s$$
Simplify using the law: $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$.
$$2^8 = 2^{6+s}$$
Equate the exponents (this is only allowed when the bases are equal).
$$8 = 6+s$$
$$2 = s$$
...or equivalently:
$$s = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

I would start by dividing by $64$ and multiplying by $2^S$ to give $2^S=\frac {256}{64}=4$.  Converting $256$ and $64$ to powers of $2$ seems unnecessary complication to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, think of $\frac{256}{2{^s}}$ as $256$ divided by $2^{s}$. then think of what multiplied by $64$ is equal to $256$.  Now, $2$ to what power(s) will equal this number?

Comment: Not quite sure why this is being downvoted, because realistically this might be the way they want them to do the question i.e. "see" the answer.